# Mac OSX mounted network drive name changes

Tags: macos, filesystems, network-drive

I'm working on a cocoa app that copies files to a user defined folder, and I'm currently testing it with a network drive. When I get the location of the network drive from the standard cocoa file browser, it looks like "/Volumes/Media". This works fine usually. There seems to be an issue though that I can't quite seem to work out where when I disconnect from my WIFI network, the Media drive remains mounted (I see it in /Volumes) but it is not accessible. Then when I reconnect the network, the drive is mounted to /Volumes/Media-1. I still see the original unusable /Volumes/Media drive until I restart my computer.

My question is a two parter. First, does anyone have any ideas why my drive may be staying "mounted" in my /Volumes folder even though I'm disconnected from the network. And secondly, I noticed that iTunes doesn't seem to be phased by this change of Volume name (from Media to Media-1). It is able to notice that the content it was originally accessing on /Volumes/Media, is now on /Volumes/Media-1 and continues functioning without a hitch. How might I go about detecting that name change and updating the path that I have stored in my app?

I'm trying this on OSX Lion by the way.

Comment: see [How to prevent the “-1” suffix in network drive paths?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10365/1749)

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks! I was creating a directory in my /Volumes folder and mistaking it for a network drive. If you post it as an answer I can accept it as the correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange) :

[How to prevent the “-1” suffix in network drive paths?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10365/how-to-prevent-the-1-suffix-in-network-drive-paths)